# Hazelcast - client is getting disconnected after connecting successfully

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

I am using HZ 3.4 with spring. Client is getting disconnected after connecting successfully. This is the exception in server logs "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

This is my HZ server configuration:

```
<hazelcast
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.4.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>test-local</name>
        <password>test-local</password>
    </group>

    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">log4j</property>
    </properties>

    <network>
        <port>5701</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false" />
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <members>localhost</members>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>

    <map name="*">
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <read-backup-data>true</read-backup-data>
    </map>
</hazelcast>
```

This is the server log:

```
WARN  [hz._hzInstance_1_test-local.IO.thread-in-0] 2016-10-31 13:05:04,424 - [localhost]:5701 [test-local] [3.4] hz._hzInstance_1_test-local.IO.thread-in-0 Closing socket to endpoint Address[127.0.0.1]:56219, Cause:java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

This is the error message in client logs:

```
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test-local][3.4] is STARTING
Oct 31, 2016 1:05:01 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test-local][3.4] is STARTED
Oct 31, 2016 1:05:01 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test-local][3.4] is CLIENT_CONNECTED
Oct 31, 2016 1:05:01 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerThread
INFO: 
Members [1] {
    Member [localhost]:5701
}
Oct 31, 2016 1:05:04 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [null] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Oct 31, 2016 1:05:04 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test-local][3.4] is CLIENT_DISCONNECTED
Oct 31, 2016 1:05:04 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [localhost/127.0.0.1:5701] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Oct 31, 2016 1:05:04 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test-local][3.4] is SHUTDOWN
```

Comment: Cluster is the same version? Anyhow 3.4 is pretty old, consider updating.

Comment: Ya the same version. Its working fine in QA, PROD. But failing in my local.

Comment: Any chance to test a newer version since the whole client communication architecture changed with 3.6. Best to test out latest 3.7.x version.